# Adding push notifications to a group when their count is more than one

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-notifications

Currently I have created group key for my android app so that the push notifications can be grouped together. My minimum target api level is 24 so I do not need to create any Summary Notification. What I am doing is something like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelID)
                                             .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
                                             .setContentTitle(sourceName)
                                             .setContentText(messageTitle)
                                             .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                             .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                                             .setAutoCancel(true)
                                             .setContentIntent(contentIntent) 
                                             .setGroup(GROUPID)
```

Thus I am creating the NotificationCompat Builder. The problem what I am facing is **Notifications are being grouped together after the 4th one**. The first three notifications are being displayed separately in the notification tray. When the fourth one is coming, they are grouped together. What I want to know is that **is this the default behavior and if so then how can I change it like notifications will be grouped together when the 2nd one comes?**

Answer (score 0):

Notifications will be grouped after 4, this is the default behaviour since 24. And to trigger group notification less than 4 you need to create group summary notification.